# Deleting rest of the string when "," comma is present in string

Tags: angular, typescript, csv, parsing

im using ngx-CSVtoJSON component in my angular app.

i have this sample data in a .csv file :

| Code |
| --- |
| sdfgfjhgj |
| fghfgh |
| fhjghkm,khhk |
| skds;dfhcs |
| fgjhgjkl |
| hkljollop |
| guygko |
| njkhg4@@ |
| dfg;453e2 |
| sdfghjkhjk |
| iuygbikugiug |
| jhfjkgkig |
| jyhfjjhgkgk |

when loading the data  , when there is a "," present in  data , the string acts weird and turn into this :

```
{
    "code": "\"fhjghkm"
}
```

the value supposed to be this : "fhjghkm,khhk";
here is my convert method :

```
  <div class="pb-2">
          <Ngx-CSVtoJSON (onConvert)="convert($event)" (onFail)="onError($event)">
          </Ngx-CSVtoJSON>
        </div>

convert(objArray){

    this.newCodeFormData.codes = objArray.result.map(a => a[this.csvFieldName]);
    this.newCodeFormData.codes = this.newCodeFormData.codes.filter(x => x != '' && x != null);

}
```

Comment: "CSV" stands for "Comma separated values". So indeed, if a value contains a comma, it won't work. If your column separator is different from ",", I believe you'd have to configure the library so it understands where to split.

Comment: `ngx-CSVtoJSON` does not support having a different separator, since the comma is hard coded in its source code: `obj[prop[k]] = line.split(',')[k]`. It also means it does not support escaped character (because you can escape commas in a CSV file if a value contains a comma)

Comment: What's the specific question you're asking?  Is it "why does this happen?" or "how can I fix it?"  The answer to the first seems to be mostly what @Random said.  The answer to second is almost certainly "use a different csv parser".  Which of those constitutes an answer to the question someone can post, or find a dupe target for?

Comment: as @Random said , CSV stands for "Comma separated values" and i didn't know it actually , i guess i just need to use a different parser that recognize  the comma character "," , so i can delete it , or replace it with a empty string

Comment: @jcalz 
my original problem is to write a logic based on the recognition of the comma in a value of the .csv file , if there is , turn an object "hasComma" value into true so i can  change the style of the DOM.

Comment: Okay but I asked what your question is, not the use case. The post describes a problem you have, but not explicitly what your question is. Usually in such cases the question is either "why is this happening" or "what's the right way to do this". Often people want answers to both, and usually answers will cover both, but the primary question should be just one of them (otherwise it's hard to categorize questions or point to existing answers).  So, which of those is your primary question?  If it's neither and you really want to ask about your use case, please [edit] to ask about that instead.

Comment: @jcalz , Oh , i must've misunderstood you , yes my original problem was why this is happening. i solved it by using [PapaParse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-papaparse) library , for angular , it has all the feature and solved my problem that i had with one of my objects containing comma character ',' .
Cheers ;)